# How to hit a rest api url from asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Actually I want to hit a url(if i hit same url from browser, SMS is coming to my number but not from the code) to send sms on mobile. the same code is working for me in C# windows app but in mvc it's giving error as excption[*An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.*]

### Sample code in MVC-5

```
    void sendSMS(string name, string mobile)
    {
        try
        {
            string mobNumber = mobile; 
            string message = "Hello "+name+" your request submitted successfully.";
            string apiToken = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
            string smsSender = "xxxxxx";
            string apiKey = "test@gmail.com";

            string url = "http://somewebsite.com/Restapis/send_sms?api_key=" + apiKey + "&api_token=" + apiToken + "&sender=" + smsSender + "&receiver=" + mobNumber + "&msgtype=1&sms=" + message + "";

            GetRequest(url, mobNumber);

        }
        catch(Exception ex){ }
    }

    public async static void GetRequest(string url, string mob)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    HttpContentHeaders headers = content.Headers;
                    if (response.ReasonPhrase == "OK") { }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Above same code is working in windows App but not in ASP.NET MVC.

Please anyone provide a hint or solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this link hope it should solve your problem
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25141/consuming-an-asp-net-web-api-call-in-an-mvc-controller

Comment: The error message contains the solution. Did you read it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in ASP.NET.

Replace this line:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
```

With this:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false))
```

You need to use `ConfigureAwait` or the threads will block.

Check [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alazarev/2017/05/20/fun-with-configureawait-and-deadlocks-in-asp-net/) for more details.

> So, according to it, ASP.NET has a specialized sync context, that only
>   one thread can have. And if you don’t use .ConfigureAwait(false), it
>   tries to restore old context, which belongs to the main thread that is
>   blocked by .Result, hence deadlock.